# Getting error when using Restriction in hibernate-criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate and learning about the HCQL(Hibernate Criteria Query language)and tried running below code but getting warning-'The method createCriteria(Class) from the type SharedSessionContract is deprecated'

```
Criteria myCriteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
        Criterion nameCriteria = Restrictions.eq("name", "Amit");        
        myCriteria.add(nameCriteria);
```

So I searched on Google and tried the below code but now getting the error in myCriteria.add(nameCriteria) method -'The method add(Criterion) is undefined for the type CriteriaQuery'

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> employeeRoot=criteria.from(Employee.class);
        criteria.select(employeeRoot);
        Criterion nameCriteria = Restrictions.eq("name", "Amit");        
        criteria.add(nameCriteria);
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are trying to combine both APIs. `Restrictions.eq()`  is a proprietary Hibernate API and you can't use it with `CriteriaQuery`. If you want to use JPA Criteria API you could rewrite this query something like this:

```java
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> employeeRoot = criteria.from(Employee.class);
        criteria.select(employeeRoot)
                .where(
                        builder.equal(
                                      employeeRoot.get("name"),
                                      "Amit")
                 );
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
        Employee emp = query.getSingleResult();
```

[See reference docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)